# Latex: auxiliary calculation

Tags: equations, align, box

when I make auxiliary calculations using pen and paper, I make some sort of extra "box", which is open on one side and has some wave-like left side. For me, this is a clear and easy way to separate auxiliary calculations from the main calculation. Do you think that there may be something similar possible in LaTeX? Inside and outside an "align"?

[image: This is how it looks like: here I am making a substitution]

Comment: Welcome. // The answer is: Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I did it the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% create boxes:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0pt, colback=white,
    borderline north={1mm}{0mm}{black}, 
    borderline south={1mm}{0mm}{black}, 
    borderline west ={1mm}{2mm}{black}
}

\begin{document}
This is my calculation:
\begin{align}
    A=A_1+A_2
\end{align}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    We use:
    \begin{align*}
        A_1&=2\pi r^2\\
        A_2&=l^2
    \end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{align}
    A=2\pi r^2+l^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Which is quite nice!

Comment: tcolorbox is one of the most, if not the, best package out there.